# Stream pausing when turning the wrist - watchOS / Swift

Tags: swift, watchos

I'm creating an app for Apple Watch that is streaming audio through the watch speaker, but I noticed that when I'm turning my wrist and the screen become black the stream is pausing.

There is something that I can do for avoid this problem? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar issue and in my case this was being caused by incorrectly activating the audio session.

Typically, for iOS, the AVAudioSession is activated using `session.setActive(true)`, however you need to handle this differently for background audio on WatchOS. Make sure you are using `session.activate()` which asynchronously activates an audio session for WatchOS ([Link: Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/2962797-activate))

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you have any code to share about session.activate? I don't know which options to assign! It will be really helpful ! Thanks a lot :)